# nodejs, make https request to backend server

Tags: node.js

Using https request, I was trying to connect to backend server using the below documentation guide:
http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback

```
    function getHttpsReq (request, response)
    {
        var options = {
            hostname: 'encrypted.google.com',
            port: 443,
            path: '/',
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            strictSSL: false,
            agent: false,
            method: 'GET'
        }

        https.request(options, function(res) {
            console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
            console.log("headers: ", res.headers);
            var data = '';
            res.on('data', function(d) {
                process.stdout.write(d);
                data += data + d;
            });
            res.on('end', function() {
                console.log("Done");
                response.end(data);
            });
        });
    }
```

But when I am trying this, it is throwing the below error:

> Error: 140735290610048:error:0607907F:digital envelope
>   routines:EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA:expecting an rsa
>   key:../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/evp/p_lib.c:288:

```
  $ node --version
  v0.8.15
```

Please let me know what I need to do extra?

Comment: Did you try using request for these things? https://www.npmjs.org/package/request

Answer (score 0):

What you need are the certificates to your domain.

This can be added using the below code.

```
key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/domain.key'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/domain.crt')
```

to your options.

The certificates can be obtained using a trusted authority or you can use self signed certificates. But self signed certificates would generate an error on client's side if it is not added to the trusted certificates in client's machine.

Comment: I tried this by creating self signed certificate to communicate to backend server from nodejs server, so here nodejs web server is client. But I am facing the same issue, even after setting "process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;" same issue.